# The difference of change of bases and change of basis

Tags: terminology

The difference of change of bases and [change of basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) is?

A little question.

Are they the same?

At the bottom of the wiki's page, External links, you can see change of bases.

Comment: Same thing, change of shirt, change of shirts.

Comment: @AndréNicolas good to know that. Should I delete this?

Comment: It is a legitimate question and shows people teaching that small changes in terminology can cause problems to someone trying to be very careful about the meaning of mathematical words.